# How is \onslide supposed to behave with the plus operator?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I'm writing a presentation, using the `beamer` document class, with a long sequence of overlays. Since I know I will have to insert new slides in the middle of the sequence, I'm trying to use the plus operator in the overlay specifications.

If I try to specify `\onslide<+-+>{<text>}`, however, I would expect the *text* to be on two subsequent slides. That's at least what happens when I use numbers instead of the plus sign. With this syntax, anyway, the `<text>` is only displayed on one single slide.

What's the expected behaviour of such a syntax? How could I obtain the result I expected?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Allow me to quote the Beamer User Guide (section 9.6.4):

> The effect of the +-sign is the following: You can use it in any
>   overlay specification at any point where you would usually use a
>   number. If a +-sign is encountered, it is replaced by the current
>   value of the LaTeX counter beamerpauses, which is 1 at the beginning
>   of the frame. Then the counter is increased by 1, **though it is only
>   increased once for every overlay specification, even if the
>   specification contains multiple +-signs** (they are replaced by the same
>   number).

(emphasis is mine)

As an example, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
   \begin{document}
      \begin{frame}
         \thebeamerpauses

         \onslide<+->{
             text

             \thebeamerpauses
         }
         \onslide<+->{
              text

              \thebeamerpauses
         }
      \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

At the beginning of the frame the `beamerpauses` counter is set to 1 (first slide). The content of the first `\onslide` command goes into the first slide and then the `beamerpauses` counter is increased by 1, so that the content of the second `\onslide` command will be shown in the second slide and then the counter will be increased again.

You could achieve your goal (assuming the subsequent slides are slides 2 and 3) with `\onslide<+-3>{text}`, so that the content will be shown in in slides 1,2 and 3 and if you add another `\onslide<+->{text}` after the first its content will be shown from slide 2 on. But I'm not sure this is an actual solution for your problem since you have not provided enough context about your second question.