# Different item symbols in a single list

Tags: beamer, lists

I want this enumerate list to the following things:

1. Only the questions are labeled by (a), (b), (c). The answers should
   not be labeled at all.
2. These six lines should appear one by one. At
   first, only the first question is shown, followed by its answer
   after I press next page. Then the second question, then the second
   answer, ...

   ```
   \documentclass[]{beamer}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Example}
   \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
   \item<1-> Q: what is the answer to the first question?
   \item<2-> A: The answer is A.
   \item<3-> Q: what is the answer to the second question?
   \item<4-> A: The answer is B.
   \item<5-> Q: what is the answer to the second question?
   \item<6-> A: The answer is C.
   \end{enumerate}
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility is to create a custom empty `item` command:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\newcommand{\answer}{\item[]} %new code
\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
 \begin{enumerate}[<+->][(a)]    %new code          
  \item Q: what is the answer to the first question?
  \answer A: The answer is A.
  \item Q: what is the answer to the second question?
  \answer A: The answer is B.
  \item Q: what is the answer to the second question?
  \answer A: The answer is C.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I also removed the individual overlay specifications and added an `+-` operator that affects the entire list.

[image]

---

As noted in the comments by @moewe, the code can be made more compact by adding the reused elements to the custom items definitions:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\item[] A: The answer is #1.}  %new code
\newcommand{\question}{\item Q:}   %new code
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
 \begin{enumerate}[<+->][(a)]               
  \question what is the answer to the first question?
  \answer{A}
  \question what is the answer to the second question?
  \answer{B}
  \question what is the answer to the second question?
  \answer{C}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as as before. I'm not doing the same for the "what is the answer to..." parts because I suspect those are there just for the sake of the MWE

Comment: This `<+->` option is an abbreviated version of `<1->`, `<2->`, ..., right?

Comment: @PatrickLi kind of, see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148308/how-is-onslide-supposed-to-behave-with-the-plus-operator/148319#148319) answer for an explanation of the `+-` usage.

Comment: It might not be a bad idea to move the "A: " into the `\answer` as well `\newcommand{\answer}{\item[] A: }` and define a new command `\newcommand{\question}{\item Q: }` and use it as `\question what is the answer to the first question \answer 42`.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I agree. Extending your reasoning, you could eventually want to add to the `answer` item the repetitive part, like `\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\item[] A: The answer is #1.}` And then use it as `\answer{A}`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use `[]` to specify empty item labels. Definitely you can define your own macros as well for items like this.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
 \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item<1-> Q: what is the answer to the first question?
  \item[]<2-> A: The answer is A.
  \item<3-> Q: what is the answer to the second question?
  \item[]<4-> A: The answer is B.
  \item<5-> Q: what is the answer to the second question?
  \item[]<6-> A: The answer is C.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```